# mini cart is not working magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

When I add new product to cart. It is adding that products to cart but mini cart doesn't shows anything.
and my console has following error.

```
TypeError: this.itemRenderer is undefined
```

can anyone tell what is because of this.

Comment: It seems that either issue can be inside your xml file. Try to follow steps as on this post, https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3894  Also block needs to be same as this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774900/typeerror-this-itemrenderer-is-undefined-magento-2. This might help

Comment: Did you do any layout, block modification to mini cart via custom module or custom theme?

Answer (score 1):

I think you changed the block from 'minicart' to a another block.
Please make sure that the checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml
(vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml)
have the same block, in which the 'itemRenderer' was set.

Comment: I m not getting your answer.. can you please tell me in details??

Comment: @AsishHira , Did you get any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add this.

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="itemRenderer" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="default" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
        <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
        <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Inside your `<item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">` tag it will remove this error.

There us another way you can add minicart to desired block by just moving minicart block using this.

```
<move element="minicart" destination="your.container.name" />
```

This way you don't need to add missing arguments, I hope this will help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete Magento_Checkout/layout folder from your theme.